# Attempting to break out parts of a controller in rails - how to approach namespacing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to break out parameter handling logic from my controllers, and am aiming to use directories/namespaces like:

`controllers/resource_name/controller.rb
controllers/resource_name/params.rb`

and

`ResourceName::Controller, ResourceName::Params`

but this feels like an uphill battle. What's the right way to use a namespace for my resource's controller/parameter classes? I feel like:

`ResourceName::ResourceNameController`

is just about the worst of both worlds.

Specifically I've had problems with gems that assume the normal constant name style, and the routing engine, that ended up needing:

`resources :resource_name, controller: 'resource_name/'`

to make it work - the controller parameter here taking advantage of directory style namespace resolution to resolve to just 'controller'

Comment: That's a rather unusual way of breaking logic for rails. What problem are you trying to solve with this?

Comment: I guess you are trying to refactor your controller

Comment: Majority of the fat in our controllers pertains to processing params before hitting `#update_attributes` - I'm looking to move that out into dedicated classes before further refactoring

Comment: It's usually done via form object. You can build something on your own or use a gem like [dry-validation](http://dry-rb.org/gems/dry-validation)

Comment: If I understand the situation correctly, I think most of the code should go into  model helper

Comment: Those dedicated classes are just models and should go under the models directory, or under models/<resource>. I second the suggestion about the form object. The reform gem is also an excellent option.

Comment: These are interesting ideas that I'll look into. That said I have another use case that the above applies to - subresource controllers, as per: http://jeromedalbert.com/how-dhh-organizes-his-rails-controllers/ in the example given I disagree with the constant name `InboxesController` in that context - the `Inboxes` namespace surely ought to contain the unfiltered inbox controller, ie `Inboxes::Controller`, akin to my original question

Comment: There are conventions in rails. Naming controller like `ResourceController ` is part of those conventions. Everything in rails is tightly coupled with the default way of naming models, controller, routes etc.

If you don't like them and don't want to follow them, you probably want to choose another framework, cause there is no good way around it

Comment: That's kind of an evasive answer don't you think? I'm aware and a big fan of strong conventions in rails of course, but using them to shut down discussion is unhelpful.

In the linked article DHH does not discuss directory layout and what he does for the 'parent' resource controller (except to say that it isn't namespaced, which I find weird). I'm hoping to clarify that part, because to my mind the 'parent' resource has no reason to be in a different namespace/directory to the sub resource - this happens to apply to the original question, though I see now that a form object would be better.